# Capifony executing `symfony:assets:install' error

Tags: git, capistrano, capifony

this is my deploy.rb

```
set :application, "uda"
set :domain,      "gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com"
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/html/"
set :app_path,    "app"

set :user,        "root"
set :use_sudo,    false
#default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:port] = 22
set :php_bin, "/usr/bin/php"

set :scm,         :git
set  :repository,  "ssh://root@10.0.0.59/~/repos/uda.git"

set  :deploy_via,             :remote_cache

# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `subversion`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

set :branch,      "master"

# Or: `propel`
role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain                         # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,         domain, :primary => true       # This is where Rails migrations will run

set :update_vendors, false
set :dump_assetic_assets, true
set  :keep_releases,  5

# 
 ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
# set :model_manager, "doctrine"

set :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.ini"]
set :shared_children,     [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads", "vendor"]
```

and I´m getting this error:

```
* executing "find /var/www/html/releases/20120127122827/web/css /var/www/html/releases/20120127122827/web/images /var/www/html/releases/20120127122827/web/js -exec touch -t 201201271228.29 {} ';'; true"
    servers: ["gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com"]
    [gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] executing command
*** [err :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] find:
*** [err :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] «/var/www/html/releases/20120127122827/web/css»
*** [err :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] : No existe el fichero o el directorio
*** [err :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] 
*** [err :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] find:
*** [err :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] «/var/www/html/releases/20120127122827/web/images»
*** [err :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] : No existe el fichero o el directorio
*** [err :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] 
*** [err :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] find:
*** [err :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] «/var/www/html/releases/20120127122827/web/js»
*** [err :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] : No existe el fichero o el directorio
*** [err :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] 
    command finished in 75ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing `symfony:assets:install'
  * executing "cd /var/www/html/releases/20120127122827 && /usr/bin/php app/console assets:install web --env=prod"
    servers: ["gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com"]
    [gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] executing command
 ** [out :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
 ** [out :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] 
 ** [out :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] 
 ** [out :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] 
 ** [out :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] [ErrorException]
 ** [out :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] Warning: copy(web/bundles/framework/css/exception.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/shared/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Util/Filesystem.php line 43
 ** [out :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] 
 ** [out :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] 
 ** [out :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] 
 ** [out :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] assets:install [--symlink] target
 ** [out :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] 
 ** [out :: gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] 
    command finished in 1797ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/html/releases/20120127122827; true"
    servers: ["gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com"]
    [gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] executing command
    command finished in 67ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/html/releases/20120127122827 && /usr/bin/php app/console assets:install web --env=prod'" on gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com

/Users/gitek/www/uda
```

Any help??????

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437991/problems-with-cap-deploy-a-symfony2-project-cant-find-app-bootstrap-php-cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your workstation perform php app/console assets:install web  without --symlink option to copy all the assets. Commit and push changes and try again with cap deploy.